# Swift : IBaction in tableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift, parse-platform, ibaction

I have a button in a cell.
When i press it i have this error : "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Any idea ?
This is my code :

```
    @IBAction func followButton(sender: AnyObject) {


if tableView != nil {

    if var indexPath :NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {



        let user:PFObject = self.userList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
        var relation : PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("KfriendsRelation")
        relation.addObject(user)
        PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeed:Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {

            }

        }


    }


   println("not working")

}
```

Comment: What line here produces this error?

Comment: In the let indexPath line.

Comment: Try using var instead of let in the error line

Comment: You clicked on a button, your selected row hasn't changed. You should send the action to the `UITableViewCell` and then redirect that event with the context to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tableView` might be `nil` at this moment, so double check that.

Also, when user taps on a button in a cell, the button handles touch, so this cell may not be selected. You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a tableView to handle taps, or in that `followButton(sender:)` method get location of the touch, and then get index path using `tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(_:)` method.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that even to my worst enemy.